# Creating a Firestore Plugin for GatsbyJS

Tags: gatsby

I am trying to create my own source plugin for Gatsby.  In this particular case, I am trying to create a firestore source plugin.  I know that there already exists source plugins for firestore, but I would like to learn how to create source-plugins myself in general and from a database in particular (I've already gone through the [fetch api source plugin tutorial](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/pixabay-source-plugin-tutorial/) on the gatsby site).

With that said, the plugin is not working and I'm not sure what the problem is.  I have already done a console.log and I know that the data is being retrieved for firestore.  Also, there are no errors when I do a `gastby develop` in the console.  The site builds properly -- and I can access `graphiql`.  But, the data does not show up in graphiql.

Here is the `gatsby-node.js` file in the plugin:

```
const firebase = require("firebase-admin")
const firebaseCert = require("./firebase-adminsdk.json")

exports.sourceNodes = async ({
  actions,
  createNodeId,
  createContentDigest,
}) => {
  try {
    if (firebase.apps || !firebase.apps.length) {
      firebase.initializeApp({
        credential: firebase.credential.cert(firebaseCert),
      })
    }
  } catch (e) {
    report.warn("Could not initialize Firebase. Please check credentials")
    report.warn(e)
    return
  }

  const { createNode } = actions

  const db = firebase.firestore()

  db.collection("newsFeed")
    .get()
    .then(snapshot => {
      snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
        createNode({
          id: createNodeId(`feedly-feed-${doc.id}`),
          parent: null,
          children: [],
          internal: {
            type: `FeedlyFeeds`,
            content: JSON.stringify(doc.data()),
            contentDigest: createContentDigest(JSON.stringify(doc.data())),
          },
        })
      })
    })
}
```

Any idea why this is not working -- and what I can do to get it to work?

Comment: Try either creating node synchronously or returning your promise.